# Is there a way to view history in the iOS twitter app?

Tags: twitter

I read an interesting article in the iOS twitter app about a week ago. I forgot to star or retweet it and now I have no idea how to find it. Is there some way to view a web history in the Twitter app?

I posted a [related question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/173045/article-on-disruptives-vs-something-else) on programmers trying to find specific article, but it got closed :/

Comment: I don't have an answer to this question, but if it helps, the article you described on Programmers.SE sounds like "Stables and Volatiles" by [Michael Lopp](http://www.randsinrepose.com). It was published in Issue 1 of [The Magazine](http://the-magazine.org/1/stables-and-volatiles), which is available in iOS's Newsstand for $1.99 / month.

Comment: No there is no way to check a browsing history in the Twitter app. I also feel this question is too localized to be to someone else's use in the future.

Comment: "Is there a way to check history in the Twitter app?" "No." I don't see what's localized about that, regardless of the OP's reasons for asking the question.

Comment: Dan J: OMG YES YOU ARE RIGHT!!!! Thank you! That's the article! I bought a subscription and loved it and then completely forgot where I had read the article, :P. I've asked for the other question to be re-opened so you can answer and I can mark your answer as "the answer".

Comment: Jeez, someone just answer "no" so I can mark that as the answer. Why isn't this a valid Q&A? Stack Exchange has become extremely unfriendly these days :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There isn't a way to view the history.